# create categorical variable in sas based upon date

Tags: date, variables, sas

I want to create a categorical variable based upon date and input the following code.

```
data temppricedata;
    set SASHELP.PRICEDATA;
    date_group='';

    IF (date>='MAR2002'd) THEN
        date_group='new';

    IF (date<'MAR2002'd) THEN
        date_group='old';
run;
```

However I got error like

```
    ERROR: Invalid date/time/datetime constant 'MAR2002'd.
    ERROR 77-185: Invalid number conversion on 'MAR2002'd.
```

I am sure the format follows sas date format which is MONYY. 
I do not know how to correct this.

Comment: Nope, it's DDMONYY.  See [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000780334.htm).

Comment: thanks! yeah it works now with 01mar02 or 01mar2002

Comment: @Jeff  Would you please post that as a full answer so that both you and the OP may enjoy the benefits?

Comment: Depending on the volume of data, I'd suggest adding an `else` statement between the two `if` statements to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jeff mentioned, the correct way for specifying SAS date constants is DDMONYY or DDMONYYYY.

```
 data temppricedata;
        set SASHELP.PRICEDATA;
        length date_group $3.;
        IF date >= '01MAR2002'd THEN date_group='new';
        ELSE IF date <  '01MAR2002'd THEN date_group='old';
    run;
```